# np.where() do nothing if condition fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a sample from my dataframe:

```
       Created      Insert Time   MatchKey              In Previous    New Type
18593  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LXGS090393APIN040640       No        New Existing
5517   2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LIN380076CI166203726       No        New Existing
2470   2018-02-12   2018-02-19    CI164414649APIN160672      No        New Existing
13667  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LIN257400APIN015446       Yes        New Existing
10998  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LXSV225786APIN158860      Yes        New Existing
20149  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LIN350167APIN158284       Yes        New Existing
20143  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LIN350167APIN161348       Yes        New Existing
30252  2016-08-12   2018-02-19    LXGS120737APIN153339      Yes        New Existing
12583  2016-08-09   2018-02-19    WIN556410APIN157186       Yes        New Existing
28591  2018-05-03   2018-02-19    CI195705185APIN009076      No        New Created
```

I wanted to replace values in **New Type** column in a way that if the condition is failed the function does nothing:

```
current['New Type'] = np.where(current['In Previous']=='Yes','In Previous',pass)
```

but apparently it causes a syntax error as np.where() doesn't handle **pass**:

```
File "<ipython-input-9-7f68cda12cbe>", line 1
current['New Type'] = np.where(current['In Previous']=='Yes','In Previous',pass)

                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What would be an alternative to achieve the same?

Comment: `where` isn't an `if/else` clone.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just return the column instead of `pass` this is the same as doing nothing when the condition is `False`:

```
current['New Type'] = np.where(current['In Previous']=='Yes','In Previous',current['New Type'] )
```

Or you can just mask those rows:

```
current['New Type'] = current.loc[current['In Previous']=='Yes', 'In Previous']
```

Comment: ho would you assing a constant value to the matching row in the first case.  so not column 'In Previous', but instead 'SomeConstantValue'

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for exactly this purpose:

```
df['New Type'].mask(df['In Previous']=='Yes', 'In Previous', inplace=True)
```

Somewhat confusingly, you have to remember that `pd.Series.mask` updates a value when a condition is met, while `pd.Series.where` updates a value when a condition is *not* met.

Comment: I have TypeError: mask() got multiple values for argument 'inplace'. Why?