# Speeding up pandas multi row assignment with loc()

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to assign value to a column for all rows selected based on a condition. Solutions for achieving this are discussed in several questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263020/pandas-update-value-if-condition-in-3-columns-are-met) one.
The standard solution are of the following syntax:

```
df.loc[row_mask, cols] = assigned_val
```

Unfortunately, this standard solution takes forever. In fact, in my case, I didn't manage to get even one assignment complete.

Update: More info about my dataframe: I have ~2 Million rows in my dataframe and I am trying to update the value of one column in my dataframe for rows that are selected based on a condition. On average, the selection condition is satisfied by ~10 rows.

Is it possible to speed up this assignment operation? Also, are there any general guidelines for multiple assignments with pandas in general.

Comment: please explain a bit more your use case, the size of the dataframe, etc... to help speed up if possible, because `loc` is pretty standard to access several rows at once and in most of the case it is fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `.loc` and `.at` are the differences you're looking for. `.at` is meant to be faster based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022658/11588364).

Comment: ```at()``` does not provide any significant speedup, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could give np.where a try.

Here is an simple example of np.where

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['B'] = np.where(df['B']< 50, 100000, df['B'])
```

[np.where() do nothing if condition fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782443/np-where-do-nothing-if-condition-fails)
has another example.

In your case, it might be

```
df[col] = np.where(df[col]==row_condition, assigned_val, df[col])
```

I was thinking it might be a little quicker because it is going straight to numpy instead of going through pandas to the underlying numpy mechanism. This article talks about Pandas vs Numpy on large datasets: [https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-testing-pandas-vs-numpy-ffbf80070ee7#:~:text=Numpy%20was%20faster%20than%20Pandas,exception%20of%20simple%20arithmetic%20operations](https://towardsdatascience.com/speed-testing-pandas-vs-numpy-ffbf80070ee7#:%7E:text=Numpy%20was%20faster%20than%20Pandas,exception%20of%20simple%20arithmetic%20operations).